# How to create a method that searches an input file

Tags: java

I am working on a project where I have to create a parser.  The idea of the project is for a method lex() to act as a lexical analyzer and scan an input file which I will include below.  the file includes a line in the input file stating which statement is being parsed and then each token of this statement below the statement.  I created an `enum` of tokens to be compared to in my `lex()` method.  What my lex method should do is use a scanner to find the next line of the file, compare it to the enum, and if it matches, store it in `nextToken` and then return it.  My issue is that I cannot figure out how to deal with when the `nextLine()` and `tokens.toString()` do not match which would indicate that either the file is empty, it is the end of file, or the line it is comparing is "Parsing the Statement: statement".  How could I update my `lex()` method of

```
public static tokens lex()
    {
        String str = scanner.nextLine();

        while(str != null)
        {
            for(tokens token : tokens.values())
            {
                if(str.equals(token.toString()))
                {
                    tokens nextToken = token;
                    return nextToken;
                }

            }
        }
        return nextToken;
```

to be able to handle the parsing the statement lines and only compare the tokens.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Parse 
{
    //Scanner to read for each line of the input file
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner("statements.txt");
    private static tokens nextToken = null;
    public static String str = null;
    public static PrintStream outputPrint;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
    {

        outputPrint = new PrintStream("lexOutput.txt");
        outputPrint.println("********************************************************************************");
        outputPrint.println("Shane Hampton, CSCI4200, Fall 2019, Parser");
        outputPrint.println("********************************************************************************");
        /*lex();

        if(nextToken != null)
        {
            if(nextToken == tokens.IDENT)
            {
                outputPrint.println
                outputPrint.println
            }
        }
        else
        {
            outputPrint.println(str);
        }*/

    }

    /** Lex Method to return the token from each line when called **/
    public static tokens lex()
    {
        String str = scanner.nextLine();

        while(str != null)
        {
            for(tokens token : tokens.values())
            {
                if(str.equals(token.toString()))
                {
                    tokens nextToken = token;
                    return nextToken;
                }

            }
        }
        return nextToken;


        /*while(str != null)
        {
            for(tokens token : tokens.values())
            {
                if(str.equals(token.toString()))
                {
                    tokens nextToken = token;
                    return nextToken;
                }

            }
        }
        return nextToken;*/


    }/** END OF LEX METHOD **/

    enum tokens
    {
        END_OF_FILE, LEFT_PAREN, RIGHT_PAREN, ASSIGN_OP, ADD_OP, 
        SUB_OP, MULT_OP, DIV_OP, IDENT, INT_LIT
    }
    /**********************************************************/
    /* assign
      Parses strings in the language generated by the rule:
      <assign> -> id = <expr>
    */
    public void assign() throws IOException
    {
        System.out.printf("Enter <assign>\n");

        /* Parse the first expression */
        expr();

        System.out.printf("Exit <assign>\n");

    }/* End of function assign */

    /**********************************************************/
    /* expr
      Parses strings in the language generated by the rule:
      <expr> -> <term> {(+ | -) <term>}
    */
    public void expr() throws IOException
    {
        System.out.printf("Enter <expr>\n");

        /* Parse the first term */
        term();

        /* As long as the next token is + or -, get
           the next token and parse the next term */
        while (nextToken == tokens.ADD_OP || nextToken == tokens.SUB_OP) 
        { 
            lex();
            term(); 
        }
            System.out.printf("Exit <expr>\n");
    } /* End of function expr */

    /**********************************************************/

    /* term
      Parses strings in the language generated by the rule:
      <term> -> <factor> {(* | /) <factor>)
    */
    public void term() throws IOException
    {
        System.out.printf("Enter <term>\n");

        /* Parse the first factor */
        factor();

        /* As long as the next token is * or /, get the
           next token and parse the next factor */
        while (nextToken == tokens.MULT_OP || nextToken == tokens.DIV_OP) 
        { 
            lex();
            factor(); 

        }
          System.out.printf("Exit <term>\n");
    } /* End of function term */

    /**********************************************************/

    /* factor
      Parses strings in the language generated by the rule:
      <factor> -> id | int_constant | ( <expr )
    */
    public void factor() throws IOException
    {
        System.out.printf("Enter <factor>\n");

        /* Determine which RHS */
        if (nextToken == tokens.IDENT || nextToken == tokens.INT_LIT)
        {
            /* Get the next token */
            lex();

        }
        else
        {
            if (nextToken == tokens.LEFT_PAREN)
            {
                lex();
                expr();
                if (nextToken == tokens.RIGHT_PAREN)
                {
                    lex();
                }
                else
                {
                    Error(null);
                }
            } /* End of if (nextToken == ... */
            else
            {
                Error(null);
            } /* End of else */
        }
        System.out.printf("Exit <factor>\n");

    } /* End of function factor */

    /*********************************************************/

    /* Method to show an that an error exists when the method is called*/
    private void Error(String s) 
    {
        System.out.printf("There is an Error");
    }

    /*********************************************************/


}
```

```
Parsing the statement: sumTotal = (sum + 47    ) / total
IDENT       
ASSIGN_OP   
LEFT_PAREN  
IDENT       
ADD_OP      
INT_LIT     
RIGHT_PAREN 
DIV_OP      
IDENT
Parsing the statement: Total = (sum + 47    ) /
IDENT       
ASSIGN_OP   
LEFT_PAREN  
IDENT       
ADD_OP      
INT_LIT     
RIGHT_PAREN 
DIV_OP  
Parsing the statement: area = (length + width) / 2
IDENT       
ASSIGN_OP   
LEFT_PAREN  
IDENT       
ADD_OP      
IDENT       
RIGHT_PAREN 
DIV_OP
INT_LIT
Parsing the statement: ageNumbers = age + 3 - 5 * (D / C)
IDENT       
ASSIGN_OP
IDENT       
ADD_OP
INT_LIT
SUB_OP
INT_LIT
MULT_OP
LEFT_PAREN  
IDENT       
DIV_OP
IDENT       
RIGHT_PAREN 
END_OF_FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

In your while loop, there is no break condition. So if you have input `str = "any random value except those tokens"`, you fall inside an infinite loop. Since you are using `str = scanner.nextLine()`, it reads the entire line, not the tokens( ie, including tailing spaces, etc) so you get `str = "DIV_OP   "`, not `str="DIV_OP"`. There are some of the problems. 
Anyways, I have just written a sample code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Start{
    static Scanner sc;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            try{
                tokens t = lex();
                if(t != null){
                    System.out.println("Found token: "+t.toString());
                }
            }catch(Exception x){    x.printStackTrace();    }

        }
    }

    public static tokens lex(){
        tokens ret = null;
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        if(s.contains("Parsing the statement:")){
            System.out.println("Found parsing statement line!!!");
            return null;
        }else{
            //System.out.print(s);
            for(tokens token : tokens.values()){
                if(s.contains(token.toString())){
                    System.out.println("Found a token!!!");        
                    ret = token;
                    return ret;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Default case!!!"); 
        return ret;
    }

    enum tokens
    {
        END_OF_FILE, LEFT_PAREN, RIGHT_PAREN, ASSIGN_OP, ADD_OP, 
        SUB_OP, MULT_OP, DIV_OP, IDENT, INT_LIT
    }
}
```

Here, I used `str.contains("Parsing ...")` to detect those lines. Please have a look, and if you have any questions, feel free to ask.